# Two UITableViewCell have same constraint but appear different in Interface Builder

Tags: autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder, xib

I'm designing a prototype cell in Interface Builder. Another programmer built the previous cells in Storyboard before me, I'm just adding the new one in image 2 with the [Some text] label. Both cells have the same class set in interface builder, a custom UITableViewCell subclass.

**Existing cell**: has leading space to superview = 10, but somehow the constraint is pinned to some floating point in space (there is no parent view other than Content View).
[image: 1]

**My cell**: has leading space to superview = 20, but it pins the edge to the actual content view superview. If I set it to 10, they will look way different, but on paper have the exact same layout constraint (leading space = 10 to superview).
[image: 2]

So it looks almost as if there is some sort of invisible edge inset, or layout margin, but I don't see any properties in interface builder that could affect it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turns out to that you need to use the bottom toolbar button to be able to constrain your leading edge to the superview margin (with the checkbox). I was using cmd + click and drag menu, which is why I couldn't find it. Doing this in a UITableViewCell subclass pins it to a margin.

[image: use the tool button]